# What does "certain" mean in this passage?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am a ESL learner, has been recently started doing some practice test of IESLTS. Here is a question I am confused about within a reading passage.

> There had, of course, been dictionaries in the past, the first of these being a little book of some 120 pages, compiled by a ***certain*** Robert Cawdray, published in 1604 under the title *A Table Alphabeticall 'of hard usuall English wordes'.*

I am struggling with the words "certain" that author used here, I will be really grateful if someone help me figure out the question, or any of the ideas would give a lot of help.

Comment: ***Certain***: Used when mentioning the name of someone not known to the reader or hearer.
*‘a certain General Percy captured the town’* https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/certain

Comment: So the word "certain" is used to point out a person in special way in this case?

Comment: @YosefBaskin If I understand you correctly, the certain is used to point out someone specifically, am I right?

Comment: @YosefBaskin OK... But to figure something out is also really delightful! Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

The word **certain** is used here in a special way, like one particular Robert Cawdray rather than just Robert Cawdray. I might think you want an apple, but you reply "No, I don't want just any apple but a **certain** apple my grandma gave me. That apple."

In this case, there is no great need for the word except to challenge a non-native! The author is saying you don't know Cawdray but he is the **one particular** man who published the first dictionary even if you did not hear of him, as might be expected (Sorry, I do not recognize his name, either.)

In this use, **certain does not mean definite**: *I am certain your name is Xu, not X.*

Comment: No... I am the one who need to thank you! For helping me figure out this question!

Comment: There is nothing special or specific about the person being mentioned. Saying "a certain Robert Cawdray" is the same as saying "someone named Robert Cawdray",

Comment: @m - Good point. So why does the author here add the word? I would expect it where a name is unusual and we might think, really, that is actually his name?

Comment: It actually works in reverse. If I say "it was compiled by Robert Cawdray", you will ask yourself "should I know who this Robert Cawdray is?". By saying "it was compiled by a certain Robert Cawdray" I am saying you probably never heard of him and there is no good reason why you should have.

Comment: Adding 'a certain' before the name implies 'whether or not his name means anything to you'. Eg. from a secretary telling you about a caller/visitor, it usually means that they do not know him, but you might.